# Laravel validate method does not prevent user from validating

Tags: laravel, authentication, validation, request

I don't have any errors, nor on client or server. To give you more context I'm creating a login form, I'm trying to prevent the user from authenticate himself if the text he typed on the input fields are corrects. If it's not correct, the user should not be redirected to the route (which has the name "authenticate").
there are 3 routes: login and home which are pages, and authenticate that's redirecting to a controller which got all the functions related to the login.

AuthController

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login() {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Login view

```
        <form action="{{ route('authenticate') }}" method="post">
          @csrf

          <input type="email" name="email">
          <input type="password" name="password">
          <button class="submit">Log</button>
        </form>
```

All the routes

```
    Route::get('home', HomeController::class)
    ->name('home');

Route::get('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('login');

Route::get('authenticate', [AuthController::class, 'authenticate'])
    ->name('authenticate');
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is to check if the text the user has typed into the email field is an email, and if all the fields have text in it, because everything is required. But it seems like it's not the case, even if the fields are empty the log in button redirects to the authenticate page. Did I do something wrong? If I didn't provide enough information I would be glad to provide more, thanks for reading :) have a nice day

Comment: If you are using  [Laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication), use route "login" instead of "authenticate" and also check in the inspect element what status code you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add required field to your input tag

Comment: It's working but the thing is that with Laravel, if the validate method was working I would be able to tell the user what errors he got (since Laravel automatically store the error message in the $error). But that's not the case meaning HTML handles the validate, but not Laravel. So the problem is not solved properly

Comment: I don't understand this answer is accepted. this will add frontend validation, but that's not a good way of validating. It will only validate if there is something filled in, not that it's a valid email address

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    {{Session::get('success')}}
    </div>
@elseif(Session::has('failed'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
    {{Session::get('failed')}}
    </div>
@endif
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{old('email')}}" required />
    {!!$errors->first("email", "<span class='text-danger'>:message</span>")!!}
</div>
```

Try this...